# HTACCESS to rewrite ? to /

Tags: .htaccess

How can I make an htaccess to rewrite the ? in the url to a / instead?

I've tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule` like this. You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^ $0/%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: okay, i decided I didn't want it/need it and i deleted it and this happens when i go to the url $2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2

Comment: I didn't get your comment. What URL did you try? Test it in new browser to avoid caching issues.

Comment: It was due to caching, sorry.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.